When using pycaret evaluate_model , plots are not interactive
When using pycaret evaluate_model function I get
evaluate_model
but as you can see I get the pipeline plot, but even if I press the other options (like Threshold in the picture), the corresponding plots do not appear
Has anyone have this problem and how can I solve it?
I used evaluate_model and I was expecting to be able to see all the plots
